# Не работают функции у класса усовершенствованной кнопки tkinter python

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

Есть класс с усовершенствованной кнопкой из tkinter, и при создании он конфликтует с обычными кнопками (кнопки хаотично меняют расположения и параметры).

Так же не работают бинды(.bind()), и через один работают обычные команды типа destroy(), place(), lift()

Можете пожалуйста сказать что у меня не так, если таких конфликтов кнопок вообще можно избежать.

```
class Button2(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self,
                  master=None,
                  help_pad=[],
                  hovercolor='#1589ff',**argss):
        """
        улучшенный Button из tikner
        """        
        super().__init__(master,**argss)
        self.argss = argss         
        
        
        if type(help_pad) == list:
          self.help_pad_text = help_pad[0] if len(help_pad) >=1 else None
          self.help_pad_bg = help_pad[1] if len(help_pad) >=2 else '#212221'
        else:
            self.help_pad_text = help_pad
            self.help_pad_bg = '#212221'
        self.hovercolor = hovercolor
        if self.hovercolor != False:
          self.bind("<Enter>", self.focus_in)
          self.bind("<Leave>", self.focus_out)
                            
                    
        self.time_help_pad = False
                                
    def focus_in(self,event=None):
        self['bg'] = self.hovercolor
        self.time_help_pad = True
        if self.help_pad_text != None:        
            self.after(1000,lambda: self.open_help_pad(event=event))
            try:
              self.help_pad.destroy()
            except:
              pass
    def focus_out(self,event=None):
        try:
          self['bg'] = self.argss['bg']
        except:
          pass
        self.time_help_pad = False
        try:       
            self.help_pad.destroy()
            self.help_pad_state = False
        except:
            pass
    def test_to_destroy_help_pad(self):
        try:
           print(self.winfo_id())
           if self.help_pad_state == True:
                self.after(10,self.test_to_destroy_help_pad)
        except:
           try:
              self.help_pad.destroy()
           except:
                pass
    def open_help_pad(self,event = None):
        if self.time_help_pad == True:
            self.help_pad_state = True               
            self.help_pad=Button2(bg=self.help_pad_bg,text=insert_str(self.help_pad_text,50),fg='white',font=("Consolas", 14, "bold"),border=4,state='disabled')
            self.help_pad.place(x=event.x +self.winfo_x(),
                                y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height(),
                                height=25* ((len(self.help_pad_text)/50) if (len(self.help_pad_text)/50) >=1 else 1)
                                )
            self.bind("<Destroy>", self.focus_out)
            try:
              FORM.update_idletasks()
              
              if self.help_pad.winfo_x() + self.help_pad.winfo_width() >= FORM.winfo_width():
                self.help_pad.place(x=FORM.winfo_width()-self.help_pad.winfo_width())
            except:
               pass
            self.test_to_destroy_help_pad()

        
q4=Button2(FORM,command=lambda: q3.config(fg='green'),text='Down',help_pad=['Длинное описание'],width=11,height=1,font=("Consolas", 11, "bold"),bg=standart_backgraund,fg='red',activebackground=standart_backgraund,border=1,relief=RAISED)
q4.place(x=297,y=28)

q5=Button2(FORM,command=lambda: q4.place(y=q4.winfo_y()+20),text='Download2',help_pad=['Описание'],width=11,height=1,font=("Consolas", 11, "bold"),bg=standart_backgraund,fg='red',activebackground=standart_backgraund,border=1,relief=RAISED)
q5.place(x=900,y=28)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.